# Running Multiple Rabbitmq instances on a single server with multi-core c

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to scale my Rabbitmq service, to increase performance and throughput of the service.

I found a [docker-compose](https://github.com/pardahlman/docker-rabbitmq-cluster) file which runs 3 instances of Rabbitmq and joins them in a cluster.

```
version: '3'

services:

  rabbitmq1:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq1
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}

  rabbitmq2:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq2
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq1
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
    volumes:
      - ./cluster-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/cluster-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/cluster-entrypoint.sh

  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq3
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq1
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
    volumes:
      - ./cluster-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/cluster-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/cluster-entrypoint.sh
    
  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:1.7
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq1
      - rabbitmq2
      - rabbitmq3
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
```

As far as I know, Rabbitmq is not single-threaded so basically a single instance of it should be able to use all the CPU power of the server. Am I right?

I wonder if running multiple instances of Rabbit on a single server has any benefits for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess running multiple instances of RabbitMQ may not have any benefits. You have multiple queues and exchanges in the RabbitMQ which can solve the majority of the problems.

One reason for starting multiple instances as mentioned in the compose file is to have a cluster of RabbitMQ nodes which provides Clustering and Queue mirroring, High availability and more. With RabbitMQ 3.8 you have [quorum queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html).